# jQuery $.post result condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have modified this code from jQuery website by adding a condition into it. But whatever the result is, it always get in the the first 'if'. How can i make my condition work?

```
<script>
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

/* stop form from submitting normally */
event.preventDefault(); 

/* get some values from elements on the page: */
var $form = $( this ),
    term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
    url = $form.attr( 'action' );

/* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */

**//the condition doesn't work here. It always get into the first "if". Why?**
$.post( url, { s: term },
  function( data ) {
      if (var content = $( data ).find( '#content' )) {
          console.log('One or more results were found');
      } else {
          console.log('no result');
      }
  }
 );
});
</script>
```

Comment: I would just like to mention that with valid html all ID's should be unique so you wouldn't have to use `$(data).find('#content')`, you could just use `$('#content')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `$( data ).find( '#content' ).length`

In your case you are assigning `$( data ).find( '#content' )` to `var content` inside your if condition. `$( data ).find( '#content' )` returns an object, which is always `true` so it always satisfy the if condition.

if you want to check whether an element exist inside data use

```
if ($( data ).find( '#content' ).length > 0) {
      // content exist
} else {
      // empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

because you are making an assignment in the condition. it's always returned true. but if it was something like

```
if(data!="")
```

then it would be a condition.

Comment: That's not correct.  If you do if(test=false), it will go into the else clause.  The problem is that find() returns an object.

Comment: yes you're right. even if it's a assignment, the if looks into the assigned variable. sorry. and when I try it, the "var" inside the if causes an error first. how did you get past it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var content = $( data ).find( '#content' )
```

try

```
$( data ).find( '#content' ).length
```

find() always returns an object, so it will always be true.  If you do .size() you will see if it actually contains anything.